# 12v from Notebook Mainboard to attach 3.5 inch HDD

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, sata, voltage

I plan to build a low-budget low-power home server, mainly as a NAS.

My first Idea was to simply use a RPI 4, it has USB 3.0 and Gbit Ethernet, but I think the hardware is too slow to be fun.

For about the same price there are Notebook Mainboard Replacements with a Intel Core i3/i5 CPU and 4GBs of Ram on eBay, which would be much more powerfull than a Raspberry Pi and still consume much less power than a Desktop build.

I would build a custom case and buy two 3.5" HDD (much cheaper than SSDs, and cheaper/faster than 2.5" HDDs) for RAID1.

I know the connectors are the same, but the problem is, a 3.5" needs 12V where as a 2.5" only needs 5V.
Will Notebook Mainboards also provide 12V to the sata power connector?

Comment: You are more likely to find an answer if you post in http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com and include the mainboard(s) you are considering.

Comment: Most likely not, notebooks are not designed to provide that amount of voltage, but that would depend on the specific board. That said, a 12V/5V SATA power adapter can be found for well under $5 from companies like AliExpress.

Comment: Some motherboards have a 12V inside for the audio amp for example, some don't. I wouldn't take the risk and use an external 12V supply as mentioned.